# Cloned jquery form clearing all text box values when it should only clear one

Tags: jquery

Here's an image of my form to give you a better understanding

[image]

The way it works is, when you click add an image, it will clone the form and another line, this image has been cloned 4 times.

If I click anyone of the - buttons, it will remove that line, so far this is working perfect.

The issue comes when you click the - button, it should only remove that line, but it also removes all the values in the text boxes but for some reason my image input boxes remain fine?

Here's the jquery

```
function pp_updateClonedInput(index, element,param) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_pp_sets").attr("id", "ppclonedInput" +  index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "cs_product_menu_pp_src_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_pp_link_" + index + "]");
    $(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("id", "pp_text_box" + index);
    $(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("name", "hero_options[pp_text_box_" + index + "]");
    if(param)
        $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
        $(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("value", "");
        $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_pp_src_" + index + "_ppbutton");
    }



$(document).on("click", ".ppclone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pptoappend='<div id="ppclonedInput1" class="ppclonedInput"><input id="cs_product_menu_pp_src_1" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_pp_link_1]" value="" /><input id="cs_product_menu_pp_src_1_ppbutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary pp-upload-button" /><div class="button ppremove">-</div> <input id="pp_text_box1" class="pp_text_box" type="text" size="15" name="hero_options[pp_text_box_1]" value="" /> <span class="description">Slide Show Text</span>'
    if( $(".ppclonedInput").length < 1){
        // create div
        $('#upload_pp_sets').append(pptoappend);
    }
    else {
        // clone div
        var ppcloneIndex = $(".ppclonedInput").length + 1;
        var ppnew_Input = $(this).closest('.ppclonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.ppclonedInput').clone() : $(".ppclonedInput:last").clone();
        pp_updateClonedInput(ppcloneIndex, ppnew_Input,true); 
    }   
});

$(document).on("click", ".ppremove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".ppclonedInput").remove();
    $(".ppclonedInput").each( function (ppcloneIndex, ppclonedElement) {
        pp_updateClonedInput(ppcloneIndex + 1, ppclonedElement,false);
    })
});
```

If I remove the line

```
$(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("value", "");
```

it works fine, but when you click the 'add an image' button, the text box will show the previous values content, by adding that line it give me a blank form.

I can't figure out why the image input works perfect but the text boxes don't, can anyone help?

If you need anymore info, let me know.

Comment: It shouldn't even be executing that line, since `param = false` when you're deleting a line.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Give me a minute and i'll make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't the following code be between {} ?

```
if(param)
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_pp_src_" + index + "_ppbutton");
```

I mean, like this:

```
if(param) {
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:nth-child(4)").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_pp_src_" + index + "_ppbutton");
}
```